# Disable dates outside a range in Infragistics WebMonthCalendar control

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I want to disable dates which are not in between `RangeMin` and `RangeMax` from a `selectedDates` collection in an Infragistics `WebMonthCalendar` control, I have researched a bit but not found any clue.
Which WebMonthCalendar property should I have use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the WebMonthCalendar, you have two properties named `MinDate` and `MaxDate`.
They get or set the maximum and minimum date that can be selected in the calendar.
I don't know it they disable the dates outside their values, please check if this could be your answer.